# setOnClickListener crashes my wear app

Tags: java, android, onclicklistener, wear-os

I have made an app for my android phone to control a robot-car via a Raspberry Pi. The code works, but now I'm trying to port the app to an Android Wear app. However, when I try to run the app on my Wear device, it crashes on startup. From the error log, it comes from the SetOnClickListeners. How should I fix these errors? Thanks in advance!

edit: The errors given by logcat are RuntimeExceptions and a NullPointerException http://puu.sh/ctfF4/49f0abe2ef.png

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    buttonConnect = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonConnect);
    buttonConnect.setOnClickListener(this);

    buttonDisconnect = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonDisconnect);
    buttonDisconnect.setOnTouchListener(this);

    buttonReverse = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonReverse);
    buttonReverse.setOnTouchListener(this);

    buttonLeft = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonLeft);
    buttonLeft.setOnTouchListener(this);

    buttonForward = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonForward);
    buttonForward.setOnTouchListener(this);

    buttonRight = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonRight);
    buttonRight.setOnTouchListener(this);

}
```

Not sure if helpful:

```
@SuppressLint("ClickableViewAccessibility")
@Override
public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {

    if ((R.id.buttonForward == v.getId())) {
        switch (event.getAction()) {

            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                socketCommand("forward");
                break;
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                socketCommand("stop");
                break;
        }
    }

    else if ((R.id.buttonReverse == v.getId())) {
        switch (event.getAction()) {

            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                socketCommand("backwards");
                break;
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                socketCommand("stop");
                break;
        }
    }

    else if ((R.id.buttonRight == v.getId())) {
        switch (event.getAction()) {

            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                socketCommand("right");
                break;
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                socketCommand("stop");
                break;
        }
    }

    else if ((R.id.buttonLeft == v.getId())) {
        switch (event.getAction()) {

            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                socketCommand("left");
                break;
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                socketCommand("stop");
                break;
        }
    }

    return false;
}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    switch (v.getId()) {
        case R.id.buttonConnect: {

            System.out.println("ONCLICK CONNECT");
            SocketConnect.connect();
            break;
        }
        case R.id.buttonDisconnect: {
            SocketConnect.closeConnection();
            break;
        }

    }
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: please add the full error to your question

Comment: Done. A NullPointerException

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're probably creating a version of one of your existing layouts to work with the dpi requirements of your Android wear device, no?

I bet you don't have one or more of the following views with these specified ids in your activity_main.xml file:

```
buttonConnect
buttonDisconnect
buttonReverse
buttonLeft
buttonForward
buttonRight
```

Which will result in a NullPointerException.

Comment: I've made my layout in rect_activity_main.xml, as that will be my supposed screen. I left activity_main untouched, with the WatchViewStub in place. I'll try it there, thanks!

Comment: Thanks, that did it for me! Can't touch the functionality as my Raspberry is compiling something though!

Comment: I had to wait for 35 seconds and my thoughts zoned out. Thanks again C=